# VisualState commonState doesn´t work xaml

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, visualstates, uwp-xaml

I have this XAML view. The `VisualStateGroups` for the visual triggers
works fine, but the `VisualStateGroup` for the common states doesn't.

I try assign to a rectangle in the beginning and then neither work. In other  views this works fine .. :(

```
<view:NavigationStoredPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/ResponsiveStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</view:NavigationStoredPage.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="rer">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#121212"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="rer">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#121212"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" x:Name="rer" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Canvas.ZIndex="99" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Comment: I think the commonstates only work in a control.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually has to transition to one of these `CommonStates` using `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` for the state to transition. It happens automatically for a control like `Button` because somewhere in the `Button` class or its base class - there is a call to `GoToState()`.