# CommonStates not triggered automatically

Tags: uwp, storyboard, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager, visualstategroup

I am trying to use the `CommonStates` in order to animate my user control. 
I tried the following:

```xml
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="circle"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                  EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="Red"
                                             KeyTime="0:0:0.02" />
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Ellipse x:Name="circle"
             Height="280"
             Width="280"
             Fill="Green" />
</Grid>
```

I can produce the changes by manually calling `UpdateStates(true)`, but refering to the documentation the commonstates should be triggered automatically.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: there is no `UpdateStates(Boolean)` method, do you mean `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method?

Comment: yes, i meant VisualStateManager.GoToState, sorry. I am wondering why it does not get triggered by default. I read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912308/visualstate-commonstate-doesn%C2%B4t-work-xaml# which says that it should be triggered without explicit call of VisualStateManager.GoToState.

Answer (score 2):

Some controls have defined visual states and switch between them in their implementation, for example `Button` or `Checkbox`. In such case these states are listed in the documentation [like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates). Unfortunately `Grid` is not one of them so if you want similar behavior there, you will need to add event handlers and use `GoToState` manually. You can also create a custom derived class from `Grid` to have this behavior reusable.